# could someone instruct me to understand this code

Tags: python-3.x, format, rounding

```
def count_char(text, char):
  count = 0
  for c in text:
    if c == char:
      count += 1
  return count

filename = input("Enter a filename: ")
with open(filename) as f:
  text = f.read()

for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
  perc = 100 * count_char(text, char) / len(text)
  print("{0} - {1}%".format(char, round(perc, 2)))
```

Comment: it counts the number of times each char from a-z appears but is terribly inefficient, it will output the count and percentage of the text these chars were

Comment: What is the problem? What are your expected outputs and how do they differ from your actual ones?

Comment: so can someone explain the last line( format part)

Answer (score 0):

It's a script that counts the relative occurrence of letters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` in the given text file.

The first block defines a function that counts how many times the character `char` is present in the `text`:

```
def count_char(text, char):
  count = 0
  for c in text:
    if c == char:
      count += 1
  return count
```

The second block asks you to input the name of the file:

```
filename = input("Enter a filename: ")
```

and saves the contents of that file as a string in the variable `text`:

```
with open(filename) as f:
  text = f.read()
```

The third block displays the relative occurrence of characters `a` `b` `c` `d` `e` `f` `g` `h` `i` `j` `k` `l` `m` `n` `o` `p` `q` `r` `s` `t` `u` `v` `w` `x` `y` `z` in `text`.

For each of these characters, it first computes the proportion of the amount of the given characters in the text `count_char(text, char)` to the total length of the text `len(text)` and multiplies the result by `100` to convert it to percentage:

```
perc = 100 * count_char(text, char) / len(text)
```

and displays the results as a formatted string. The numbers in curly brackets are replaced by the character `char` and the percentage of its occurrence, rounded to two decimals `round(perc, 2)`:

```
print("{0} - {1}%".format(char, round(perc, 2)))
```

You can read more about string formatting in Python [here](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/).